# I have a confusion about "Did I make you understand?"

Tags: grammaticality

Consider that I have explained something to others and I want to make sure that they completely understand. So, Can I use the question here, "Did I make you understand?"

Is it incorrect or correct?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to say "Did I make myself clear?"

Comment: To answer the literal question, the question is grammatical, yes. However as @KateBunting suggests there are more idiomatic ways to ask this.

Comment: @KateBunting: and perhaps more polite. ;-)

Comment: *Did I help you understand?* is another alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Did I make you understand?"** sounds as if you've forced someone to understand.

I agree with Kate Bunting, **"Did I make myself clear?"** is more idiomatic.

You can try various questions like: **"Did you get it?"**, **"Did you understand?"**, **"Did you get the idea?"**

Comment: @Omar If this answer fits your needs, please use the green checkmark on the left to **accept** it as your question's answer.